# PL/SQL: My trigger doesn't work with raising exceptions

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

My code is:

```
create or replace trigger trig6
before update of min_salary, max_salary on jobs2
for each row
declare
exceptie exception;
cursor c is select salary
from emp_ast
where job_id=:new.job_id;
begin
for i in c loop
if i.salary not between :new.min_salary and :new.max_salary then
raise exceptie;
end if;
end loop;

exception
when exceptie then
dbms_output.put_line('Salariile angajatilor nu se afla intre limitele salariului minim si maxim');
end;
/
update jobs2
set max_salary=1000
where job_id='SA_REP';
/
```

The trigger compiled succesfully, but it doesn't raise any exception. I tried with 'raise_application_error' and it works, but I don't know why I can't do the same with exceptions.

Comment: When you put in an exception handler (`exception when exceptie then`) it means "don't raise this exception".

Comment: By the way, I suggest you consider [indenting your code](https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Programming-with-Karel/how-to-indent-your-code.html).

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it (in a trigger code you posted), it actually "works" as designed: if `salary` in `emp_ast` table isn't between `min_salary` and `max_salary` in `jobs2` table for the same `job_id`, trigger **displays** the message (using `dbms_output.put_line`) on clients that support it (such as SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or TOAD; but not in Oracle Forms or Apex), if enabled.

And that's all. Row is successfully being updated.

If you want to **raise** an error, then yes - you have to actually raise it, as you previously did with `raise_application_error`.

Meanwhile, Oracle does what you told it to do: checks certain conditions and displays the message. There's nothing here that would prevent `update`.